# How can I assigned onclick for a tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how can I assigned onclick for a tag with jquery

Exmaple:

```
<a id="abc">abc</a>
```

I want to assign onclick="test()" in the above a tag by jquery, anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() { 
    $("#abc").click(test);
});
```

Comment: Nope, should be `.click(test);` - or you start the function instead on binding it. Unless somehow `test()` returns a function, of course...

Comment: Good point.  I have edited my response based on your comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // all jQuery code should run from this event
    $('div').click(function(){
        // find the div that was clicked on:
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }); //click
}); //doc.ready
```

Source: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click

For your update request, as ecounysis said, you can bind the function, bu make sure it returns false, to prevent the real link from working (if you have a `href`):

```
function test(){
  alert("Hello");
  return false;
}

$(function(){
  $('#abc').click(test);
});
```

if you can't change `test`, you can also do:

```
$('#abc').click(function(){
      test();
      return false;
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/aseku